# Visual Studio DSL interaction with my classes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dsl, class-diagram, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-sdk

I'm getting start with DSL, I have build my DSL and I have a T4 template for generate code from a design.

I can create a new element in my project of my DSL type, I can create my design and then I have to run my T4 to generate code.

But, I can see how to work the default Visual Studio Class Diagram, it don't need to run any T4. For example when you drop a class in the diagram it shows a dialog to choose the class name and file.
When I change a class (adding properties for example) by edit the file the diagram update itself the new information (properties, methods, ...). When you add a property in a class using the diagram its update the file adding the correct property ...

How to do it? I'm newbie and I would like to find documentation about it.

Comment: The standard Visual Studio class diagrams do not use the DSL Toolkit technology, and they don't use T4. They are a direct interface to your code.

Comment: Thank John, After a little research I have assumed this so I've included the visual-studio-sdk tag in my question.
Where can I find information about do it? about using direct interface to my code.

Comment: Find information about what? [Visual Studio Modeling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57b85fsc.aspx)?

Comment: :D Yeah!, good start, I'm going to read it.